# How to read multiple lines by individual in an edit text with a value of Max=5 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have in my gui an edit text field that accepts multiple lines with a Max value of 5, and i can't find a way to display a matrix with the input values...something like this:

```
m=[m(1) m(2) m(3) m(4) m(5)];
set(handles.show,'string',m)
```

how can i store the values in the calculate callback..every time i run this, it brings me an error..

```
function masa_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to masa (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 %h_edit is the handle to the edit box
m=str2double(get(hObject,'String'));

function calculate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to agregarm (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
f = str2double(get(h_fuerza,'string')); %h_edit is the handle to the edit box

m = str2double(get(h_masa,'string')); %h_edit is the handle to the edit box

[row, column] = size(m);

for i = 1:row 
eval(m{i,:}) %evaluate each line as in MATLAB command prompt
end
```

I have the masa_callback,rigidez_callback and fuerza_callback i try to read the user input in the edit text box...so i want to pass those values to the calculate_callback as an array to perform certain operations according to the value of n...the error that i am getting is that when for example n=2, i add two values in the masa_callback column and fuerza_callback and 3 values in the rigidez_callback, those values are passed to the case n==2, and when my program tries to display for example the matrix m, it displays all the values i enter together in the spaces of m(1) and m(2)...i want to put only each separated value, not joined together!...How can i fix this,, i believe that is whith an array and a loop but i dont know how, and how to pass the array values to the equation to perform operations(as numbers) and display it as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem with the input (assuming you have your data in some cell array, and that `handles.show` refers to a text box), use `strvcat`:

```
someCellArray = {'a','b'};
m = strvcat(someCellArray{:});
set(handles.show,'string',m)
```

Your problem stems from the line

`m = str2double(get(h_masa,'string'));`

You do not want to convert the string to double.

Since the `String` property actually returns a multiline string, you have to modify your code like this:

```
m = get(h_masa,'String');

nRows = size(m,1);

for iRow = 1:nRows
eval(m(i,:));
end
```